Old show or movie involving a wizard school where a boy turns colored sand into a giant soccer ball
Hoping for an answer, but this could be a false memory.
My mother had this recorded off television on VHS in the 80s,so it would have to be made then or earlier. It was live-action, not animated.
I remember non-American accents, possibly British. A wizard or magician society. The boy goes to school and gets in trouble in various ways. At one point, they are learning to use sand of various colors to magically create a soccer ball. They have a choice of many glass-looking wands of multiple shapes and colors as well.
The boy uses way too much sand and makes a giant soccer ball, causing more trouble.
That is all I can remember. I have searched off and on for years with no answer as to what this was.
